# How to get response in other component and listen for data changes when new response come

Tags: javascript, angular, api, service, observable

This is my search service:

search.service.ts

```
export class SearchService {
    public searchResults;
    ... 
}
```

then if I want to update my search results:

```
this.searchService.getSearchbyDistrictCategoryCity(this.searchObj).subscribe(data => {
    this.searchedResults = data;
    this.searchService.searchResults = data; 
}, error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

and then in my search.results.component.ts is another component, not the one I use the service

```
this.messages = this.searchService.searchResults;
```

But I want `this.messages` to get updated every time a new response comes. I am sure it's something with the Observable but not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Think about **[looking at the documentation before posting](https://angular.io/guide/http)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
   this.searchService.getSearchbyDistrictCategoryCity(this.searchObj)
    .subscrie(data=>{
              this.searchedResults = data;
              this.searchService.searchResults = data; 
             // or this.messages = data
              this.messages = this.searchService.searchResults;
            },error=>this.errorMessage= <any>error);
```

You should set value of this.messages in callback of this.searchService.getSearchbyDistrictCategoryCity